Beanstalk deploy fails when it tries to save version to S3 with Github actions
Deploy fails and stops immediately with a blank error message:
Uploading file to bucket elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-333
Error: Deployment failed: Error: Status: 403. Message: 
My einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v22 parameters are:
        Application: 3-2-dev
         Environment: A3-2-dev
       Version Label: 28b8ae6f806a070eadbc377573764382f5550335
 Version description: test
          AWS Region: us-east-1
                File: deploy.zip
Existing bucket Name: elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-333
      AWS Access Key: ***
      AWS Secret Key: ***
 Wait for deployment: true
  Recovery wait time: 30

This problem is present now in 2 different projects living in 2 different environments of elastic-beanstalk, deploys crashing the same way on both.
I'm checking out environment logs but the error is not present in the eb-engine.log
I've tried several things:

Combinations with the aws secrets just to ensure that aws is responding with the "wrong credentials" ERROR.
Changing the einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy version to a newer since we had it on the 11th version.
Setting version label and verison description to a hardcode and simple number

I'm guessing it will have something to do with the AWS user's policies or permissions but at the moment I'm not the account owner so I need to convince the boss to add or delete some of them for example:

AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineV2
AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy


403 is a permissions error- whatever account you are using for the deploy does not have access to the bucket

We've got it working already, it was the aws policy AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineV2. We ended up detaching it, still having concerns though because we're not sure if security was somehow compromised.

You should definitely file a support case - seems that it is activated when AWS believes the key has been compromised

We got it working again 
It was the AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineV2 and worked by disabling it.
Not being the Aws user administrator is a real headache.
I had to convince the admin and the PM to give it a try. Maybe I should convince them to give me full access to the account.
Anyway, I'll investigate if someone activated the policy or if it just got an automated update.
